# CellRenderer - making multiple cells bold

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I would like to make multiple cells bold, I have arraylist with the cell names that should be bold but doesn't seem to work. My Arraylist with the cells that I want to bold is called `bibNumbers`, so far tried converting the arralist into array and putting the if statement into a loop and loop results into bolding variable

//edit

added example, so now id want all the 0's and 1's in the column 2 to be bold.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class as extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;
private ArrayList<String> ShadowBibNumber;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    as frame = new as();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public as() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    ShadowBibNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    ShadowBibNumber.add("0");
    ShadowBibNumber.add("1");
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tableModel.addColumn("column 0");
    tableModel.addColumn("column 1");
    tableModel.addColumn("column 2");
    tableModel.addColumn("column 3");
    tableModel.addColumn("column 4");

    new JScrollPane(table);

    table = new JTable(tableModel);

    table.setEnabled(false);

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    JScrollPane scrollPaneForTable = new JScrollPane(table);
    contentPane.add(scrollPaneForTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        tableModel
                .addRow(new Object[] { i, i, i, i, i });

    }

    table.getColumn("column 2").setCellRenderer(new boldRenderer());


}

class boldRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        for (Object x: ShadowBibNumber) {
            if (table.getValueAt(row, 2).equals(x)) {
                cellComponent.setFont(cellComponent.getFont().deriveFont(
                        Font.BOLD));

            } else {
                cellComponent.setFont(cellComponent.getFont().deriveFont(
                        Font.PLAIN));
            }
        }
            return cellComponent;

    }
} }
```

Comment: Did you add `BoldRenderer` (note that start with B) to the jtable?

Comment: making multiple cells bold == use and to test for int row, int column, for better workaround to override boolean isSelected/boolean hasFocus (depends on)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: this worked for singular cells, but now i need to make it so it bolds multiple cells

Comment: its just gonna be a table with data, and if name abc and abd make them bold, and these names are stored in ArrayList

Comment: Tips: 1) Add @mKorbel (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) **Post a MCTaRE.**

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: added MCTaRE, and you call it unrelated? its not even the proper thing, just a quick thing with useless names... as if you gonna be naming everything properly in MCTaRE...